# Transient variable is loosing the pointer to the file

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have VF page which I try to upload file.

The maximum file that I can upload is 130KB total - which does not make sense. (after that I get the view state error).

Due to a logic that determined ahead, I cannot use remote action to save the file and then connect it to the object.

I tried to use the transient keyword but between functions in my controller it's losing the pointer to the file.

```
 <input type= "file" Id= "fileinput"/>
   <apex:commandButton onclick="uploadFiles(); return false;" value="Upload"/>
```

And the "uploadFiles" JS function is :

```
var maxStringSize = 6000000;
    var attachmentList;
    var j;
    function uploadFiles()
    {
        input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
        attachmentList = input.files;
        console.log("attachmentList",attachmentList);
        if(j == undefined) 
        j = 0;   
        var file;
        if(j < attachmentList.length)
        {
            file = attachmentList[j];
         var name = file.name;
            var reader = new FileReader();  
            reader.onload = function(e) {  
             var b64 = reader.result.replace(/^data:.+;base64,/, '');                    
                console.log(b64.length);
                if(b64 .length > maxStringSize )
                alert("File size is too large to handle");
                else
                {
                    j++;
                    saveFileAF(b64 , name);
                }
            }
             reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('this is end');
            
        }
        
     }
```

and that function called an action fcuntion method that calls the function "saveFile" on my controller:

```
 <apex:actionFunction name="saveFileAF" action="{!saveFile}" oncomplete="uploadFiles();"  status="statusSaveTrip">
         <apex:param name="base64File" value="" assignTo="{!base64}"/>
         <apex:param name="fileName" value="" assignTo="{!fileName}"/>
     </apex:actionFunction>
```

Now, base64 param is a transient param and I use it here in my controller :

Declaration :

```
public transient String base64;
  private String base642;

  public String getBase64()
  {
      return base64;
  }
  public void setbase64(String base64)
  {
      this.base64 = base64;
  }
  public String fileName {get; set;}
```

The action function call the next function in controller:

```
public void saveFile()
  {

      System.debug('base64' + base64);
      
      
  }
```

after that process I add products to a table in my vf page with command link :

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
    <apex:outputPanel id="addtotableId">
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showProdTables}" >

          <apex:commandLink action="{!addToTable}"  styleClass="btn btncolor" value="{!$Label.pf_Add_Item}" reRender="toRende"  status="statusSaveTrip" oncomplete="doneAdding();" /> 

     </apex:outputPanel>
   </apex:outputPanel>
 </div>
```

Back to my controller I have the addToTable function which I cant debug the base64 variable again.

The variable shouldn't save the value from the previous function?

```
public void addToTable(){
    System.debug('this.base64- > ' + this.base64); // prints null
}
```

Any help about it please?

Comment: If you use transient -- variable is not transmitted to visualforce viewstate or back, therefore you can not use transient in this case. I would advise to check for visualforce remoting -- that one has slightly higher limits

Comment: I tried. but it required me to save the file in the remote action function. I want to save the String of the base64 that I get in the remote function and use it when the user click on another button in the VF.
In different words I want to save the base64 String in the class for later use - and that I couldnt achieve.. any help with this also will be great!